# Trying to connect Gcloud App engine with Cloud Sql intance with Sails Js but getting adapter error

Tags: google-app-engine, sails.js, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I want to connect sails js app at gcloud app engine with cloud mysql instance.I have enabled my public ip network and Cloud Sql Admin Api. I have tried following in env/production.js :-

```
adapter: 'sails-mysql',
  host : 'xx.xx.xx.xxx',
  user:'user',
  password:'password',
  database:'db_name',
  pool : true
```

Also I tried same with socketPath instead host like this :-

```
 default: {
  adapter: 'sails-mysql',
  socketPath : '/cloudsql/' + 'connection name',
  user:'user',
  password:'password',
  database:'db_name',
  pool : true
```

And also used `googleCloudSQL` instead `default` key above.

But with all the cases I am having Adapter errors and connection errors .

Comment: Hello, have you added the authorized network to your instance?

Comment: @Mario Yes I added authorized network. Though it is only used if I need to access database with that network . But this is different case where I need to connect App engine with CloudSql

Comment: Could you please provide more information about the errors experienced? Maybe a StackTrace would be useful

Comment: @Mario Yes these were some of the errors
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOTeY.png